# Foreach+switch loop or isset($_REQUEST[]) or Foreach+if-else

Tags: php, performance, if-statement, foreach, switch-statement

I was wondering, in terms of performance...

If I had an $_REQUEST array of 30 elements, and I needed to grab elements to set them to new arrays using functions, when would it be better to use multiple ISSET vs FOREACH+SWITCH:

Example:

- Method 1 = 15 elements
- Method 2 = 10 elements
- Method 3 = 2 elements

**Method 1:**

```
foreach($_REQUEST['data'] as $key => $val)
{
    switch($key){
    case 'blah':
    $newarray['blah'] = $val;
    break;
    .....
    case 'blah2':
    .....
    case 'blah3':
    .....
    case 'blah4':
    .....
    }
}
```

**Method 3:**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['data']['blah'])) $newarray['blah'] = $_REQUEST['data']['blah'];
if(isset($_REQUEST['data']['blah2'])) $newarray['blah2'] = $_REQUEST['data']['blah2'];
```

I would assume for method 3 it is better to use if(isset) but I am not sure, when would it be good to use one over the other?

Comment: I will say foreach + if-else. It is better.

Comment: What happened to method 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this more consisely with `array_intersect_key` and arrays of the required keys for each:

```
$method1Keys = array_flip(['some','keys']);
$method2Keys = array_flip(['different','ones']);
$method3Keys = array_flip(['andsome','more']);

$method1KeyValueArray = array_intersect_key($_REQUEST['data'],$method1Keys);
$method2KeyValueArray = array_intersect_key( $_REQUEST['data'],$method2Keys);
$method3KeyValueArray = array_intersect_key( $_REQUEST['data'],$method3Keys);
```

Comment: Oh, this is neat, never used this b4. So if I just add the keys to the new array I can set them using array_intersect_key?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. Php has a lot of useful built in functions for arrays. They often have weird names, and the parameter orders change about, but the manual is solid and the functions very useful once you know about them

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `$newarray` will have the same keys as the source, and you're setting the same value at the matching keys.  The fastest way:

```
$newarray = $_REQUEST['data'];
```

Comment: The new arrays are smaller arrays used for organizing the data being processed.